# How to get row by cell value in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to parse excel documents and I have one question:
is it possible to get row by cell value? For example user put some number in input field and PHPExcel must find row, contains cell with user's value and return it or return error message if there is no such value in document.

Thank's.

Comment: Will the value always be in the same column? Because using something like VLOOKUP() might allow you to retrieve it more easily

Comment: Otherwise, PHPExcel doesn't provide any functionality to search all cells for a specific value; you'd have to write the code yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you know in which column you want to search, the code can be something like this:

```
for ($row = 1; $cell = $list->getCellByColumnAndRow($desired_column, $row) != ""; $row++)
{
    if ($user_input == $cell->getValue());
    {
        echo $row;
    }
}
```

If you don't know in which column you want to search, you need to add outer loop for all columns.